# other eclipse plugin dir location

Tags: eclipse, plugins, citrix

because we use citrix for some platforms, I want split eclipse launcher executable location and location for plugin / feature dirs.

How to do?

f.e.
Eclipse: c:\program files\eclipse.exe (read only drive)
Plugins: d:\eclipse\plugins (writeable drive)

with regards

Comment: Look at [Eclipse multi-user installs](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html)